# SEVERE: PWC6117: File not found - Jetty

Tags: java, jsp, jetty

We are facing this issue in production environment but unable to track it out. 
**Technology**: JSP/Servlets,
**Jetty Server Version**: jetty-distribution-8.1.15,

Following is exception, what we are getting in Jetty Logs:

2014_08_10.stderrout.log.05300:
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "%2Ftmp%2Fjetty-0.0.0.0-8090-ExpireApp.war-_ExpireApp-any-%2Fwebapp%2FExpiry.jsp" not found

The application worked fine before but end users are unable to access .jsp file and we need a restart for the same but we want to get it resolved. Please help

Comment: "The application worked fine before" - Did you do any change when it stopped working?

Comment: Yes it was working fine before. No changes was being done. 
A couple of restarts done in previous two weeks due to some deployment and that too related to some other java files not above Expiry.jsp.  but after deployment it was working fine for a week. At sudden it says that .jsp not found.

jetty created a temporary folder in tmp/ and file is already present there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh Sorry, i have not shared answer before.

Here it is:

**Issue**: By Default Jetty unpacks .WAR file in /TMP directory of Linux. The /TMP directory got cleared after some days by some scripts which i am unable to find.

**Resolution**: I have created another directory named ‘work’ in jetty, where Jetty will unpack .WAR by default, thereby preventing jetty to unpack contents in /TMP.

So issue was unpacked contents got deleted and after restart it got created again. This time i checked unpacked content before restarting so i got what issue actually was :)

Thanks all for help

Answer (score 3):

We see things like this when there is a process in the background that cleans up tmp directories and things like that.  The jsp gets compiled there and then gets scraped away and the JSP impl still believes it to be there resulting in an error like this.

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same `SEVERE: PWC6117:` error, the reason is
I changed below code(Spring mvc controller)

```
    model.addAttribute("foo", foo);
    return "foo";
```

to just

```
return model;
```