# struts 1.3 hibernate jsp mysql

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jsp, struts1

I want to map my data to a jsp page using hibernate and mysql. Everything is working fine but when i click on link it shows a 404. below is the code attached. can anyone give a solution.. Thanx in advance.

this is my `initExecute` code,

```
public ActionForward initExecute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
    TestForm test = new TestForm();
    try {
         test.reset();
         setRequiredData(test);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mapping.findForward("success");
}
```

this is my `struts-config` code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.3//EN"
      "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-config_1_3.dtd">

<struts-config>
    <message-resources parameter="resources.Application" />
    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="test" type="com.project.forms.TestForm"/>
    </form-beans>

    <global-forwards>
        <forward name="success" path="/jsp/subject.jsp"/>
    </global-forwards>

    <action-mappings>

        <action path="/Select" type="com.project.actions.TestAction" name="test" parameter="method">
            <forward name="success" path="/jsp/subject.jsp" />
        </action>
    </action-mappings>
 </struts-config>
```

and here is my `index.jsp`,

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
                       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
  <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>GlassFish JSP Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <hr/>
    <a href="Select.do?method=initExecute">Welcome</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the stack trace:

> java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'sashi'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:946)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3421)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1247)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2748)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.(Connection.java:1553)
>       at com.project.actions.TestAction.setRequiredData(TestAction.java:78)
>       at com.project.actions.TestAction.initExecute(TestAction.java:28)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>
> SEVERE: PWC6117: File "E:\All Checkouts.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\SimpleProject\jsp\subject.jsp" not found

Comment: Please suggest what to do?

Comment: Please, add all stack trace to the question.

Comment: Are you using `Jetty` server? If so, please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261690/severe-pwc6117-file-not-found-jetty) might be useful.

Comment: I'm using Glassfish v2.5.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible issues here:

1.jsp page is not found - try setting the path as `path="/WEB-INF/jsp/subject.jsp"`

2.jdbc connection is not correct - check hibernate config